# Why is the viewForAnnotation method messing up my user's location?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, annotations, location

Recently I implemented the viewForAnnotation method in my app to play with the characteristics of my annotations (images, color, etc.). The only problem is that while that function is in my code, location services are acting weird. Instead of the blue location marker "pulsing" and being relatively small, it shades an entire county blue, stops pulsing, and is rather erratic.

Here is the code I am using:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation {

        return nil

    }

    let reuseId = "pin"

    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
        pinView!.animatesDrop = false
        pinView?.pinColor = .Green
    }
    else {
        pinView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    return pinView

}
```

Is there something in this function that may be disturbing location service representation? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work:

```
if annotation is MKUserLocation {
    return nil
}
```

Instead, use:

```
if annotation.isMemberOfClass(MKUserLocation.self) {
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works. I haven't seen this used so I never would have found it. Thank you, I'll accept you in a few minutes - you were too quick for the system.